# Seperating post text and images in different locations on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the following code to remove images (and paste just the text)

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Trying to bring in the images (in a new area of the same page) I a trying to use

```
preg_match('#(<img.*?>)#', $content, $results);
```

To no avail. And I am also wondering if there is a better way than to run a function twice, or If I can separate the text and image and call them into two different divs/locations

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jlord/3680879

Answer (score 0):

**Get Only text Based content**

```
  function custom_strip_image($text) {
        $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
        return $text;
    }

    echo custom_strip_image(get_the_content());
```

**Make second function for get images list**